# How to pass image to API using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image, axios

i have the following sample code where I want to send a image to a API.

```
const axios = require('axios');
var image = 'some/image/url/example.png';

axios.post('some/api/url', {
    title: 'The quick brown fox',  
    image: image
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Unfortunately, the API doesn't accept bitmap, binary, base64 or string based images. I want to do it like this **postman** example:

[image]

Is this possible in **NodeJS**? Teach me master(s)! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the request module to easily post form data, for example:

```
let request = require('request');
let fs = require("fs");

let url = "http://httpbin.org/post"; 
var fileName = process.argv[2] || 'test.png';

let formData = {
    upload_file: {
        value:  fs.readFileSync(fileName),
        options: {
            filename: fileName,
            contentType: 'image/png'
        }
    }
};

request.post({ url: url, formData: formData}, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Upload failed: ", err);
    }
    console.log('Upload successful: response: ', body);
});
```

If you want to write a simple server to receive the file it will look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
const fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);

app.post('/post_image', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST /post_image/');
    console.log('Headers: ', req.headers)
    fs.writeFileSync('uploaded_image.png', req.files[0].buffer);
    res.status(200).send('ok');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'));
```